# Testing with gulp + babel + jasmine on nodejs

Tags: jasmine, gulp, babeljs, gulp-jasmine

I am trying to test my code with gulp-jasmine and gulp-babel:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    jasmine = require("gulp-jasmine"),
    babel = require("gulp-babel");

module.exports = function () {
    gulp.src(["index.js", "src/**/*.js", "spec/**/*[sS]pec.js"])
        .pipe(babel({
            "presets": ["es2015"],
            "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
        }))
        .pipe(jasmine())
};
```

I got

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at D:\creation\software developer\projects\javascript-project-template\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:63:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (D:\creation\software developer\projects\javascript-project-template\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:62:18)
```

Any idea about what I am missing? The code appears to break because there are still ES6 keywords used. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you add `global: true` inside the babel config?

Comment: @LimH. `events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReferenceError: [BABEL] D:\creation\software developer\projects\javascript-project-template\index.js: Unknown option: base.global
    at Logger.error (D:\creation\software developer\projects\javascript-project-template\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:43:11)
...
    at doWrite (D:\creation\software developer\projects\javascript-project-template\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:333:12)
`

Comment: @LimH. Do you need the full message? I can add an edit...

Comment: Sorry I'm out of guess! I suppose the problem doesn't lie with the plugins but your code/node_modules. But that's as far as my guess goes

Comment: @LimH. My source codes are okay, they are working with karma. Maybe the install went wrong, I got some error messages, but it is hard to know by npm when it has real errors, because by installing optional dependencies you got almost the same red lines, so you tend to ignore error messages. Do you think a gulp-babel reinstall would work?

Comment: @LimH. I have the same after reinstall. I'll check an older version, maybe the new 6.x is buggy.

Comment: you may find this interesting https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/

Comment: @LimH. I tried with babel 5.x without presets and plugins. (There are no 5.x version of them). I got the same error message. I guess it does not do the transformation runtime, so the jasmine got the es6 files instead of the es5 files.

Comment: @LimH. Here is the working version with karma and babel 5x: https://github.com/inf3rno/javascript-project-template/blob/babel/karma.conf.js (I am trying to pipe it to jasmine currently, otherwise I cannot test nodejs with source maps as far as I can tell, because the jasmine reporters do not always handle source maps very well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to sindresorhus the lib works only on file paths, so I cannot use streams: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-jasmine/issues/60#event-452847672

He suggested this approach instead:

```
require('babel-core/register');

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    jasmine = require("gulp-jasmine");

module.exports = function () {
    gulp.src(["index.js", "src/**/*.js", "spec/**/*[sS]pec.js"])
        .pipe(jasmine({
            includeStackTrace: true
        }))
};
```